# How to consume Webservice in MVC Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services

I have very simple MVC model in which i have two very simple Model classes Person and Company.

I have to cousume a Webservice to get Data about person and Company.

Can you please post some example linke where webservice is consumed to GET or/and POST.

Here is my controller index method.

`public ActionResult Index(string id)

{

    Webservice webservice = new Webservice();

}`

`[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Index(string id)

{

    Webservice webservice = new Webservice();

}`

I dont know whether to write above code in Get or Post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally i use it in the Model. For instance i have an OData service and i call it within my model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Person(int Id)
    {
        var oDataService = new ODataService(new Uri("YourURL"));
        Name = oDataService.Persons.Where(x=>x.Id == Id).Select(x=>x.Name);
    }
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int Id)
{
    return View(new Person(Id));
}
```

Comment: What if we want to manage the third-party web service in a separate class under service layer? And then in a common class that uses an instance of `Person` and `service` to do CRUDs? does that sound any better or am I barking at the wrong tree? (The main reason to manage a separate class for service is that, there will be different third-party services based on cutomer's choice)

Answer (score 1):

Model is your data. Controller will manage it. That means you should write the logic to load data in controller and convert it to your models' objects.

Comment: Thanks for you reply..Can you send me xamle how to laod in controller and convert to Model's object..

Comment: jyparask has provided you an example in another post. It will work but if you want to cover transformation with unit test, you will need to do it a bit different. This ODataService has an interface and you will need to pass the service interface as a parameter to Person. In unit test you will be able to pass a faked service, in Controller - the real one